# Modifying POST request Body when using Retrofit/OkHttp

Tags: retrofit, interceptor, okhttp

So far I have been using OkHttp for my network requests but now I would like to take Retrofit (v2) into use. 
The server that I'm communicating with requires AuthToken either as part of the Url (GET request) or inside Body (POST request).
I also need to separate requests creation from execution which is btw very nice feature of Retrofit i.e. I can pass Call object and execute/enqueue it later.

The hard part is that the AuthToken might not be available when a request is created and I would need to modify it before it gets executed. So far I've been adding a dummy authToken at creation time and replace just before execution.
This is pretty straightforward for GET request as I can add Interceptor into OkHttpClient to modify the request Url but modifying the body of a POST request is the thing I'm struggling with.

So, is there support for this use case in Retrofit/OkHttp?

Some not working sample code that would almost do the trick (tries to add authToken always when available, ends up with: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot stream a request body without chunked encoding or a known content length!

```
client.networkInterceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();

            if (request.body() == null) {
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }

            Request authorizedRequest = request.newBuilder()
                    .method(request.method(), replaceDummyAuth(request.body()))
                    .build();
            return chain.proceed(authorizedRequest);
        }

        private RequestBody replaceDummyAuth(final RequestBody body) {
            return new RequestBody() {
                @Override
                public MediaType contentType() {
                    return body.contentType();
                }

                @Override
                public long contentLength() throws IOException {
                    return -1;
                }

                @Override
                public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
                    ParametersMap map = new ParametersMap();

                    BufferedSink authSink = Okio.buffer(sink);
                    body.writeTo(authSink);

                    String authToken = SessionManager.getAuthToken();
                    if(StringUtils.hasText(authToken)) {
                        map.put("authToken", authToken);
                        String paramString = map.getParameterString();
                        authSink.write(paramString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                    }
                    authSink.close();
                }
            };
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why the content length is -1? Is it gzipped?

Comment: No it's not gzipped, I just don't know how to implement contentLength(). If I put: return body.contentLength(); I get "java.net.ProtocolException: expected 0 bytes but received 111"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no support for the use case I'm asking for so I created new issue about it for Retrofit, see [Argument pre-processor, deserialized post-processor #816](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/816)